Can we say that the better memory relation with pupil dilation is connected to sympathetic nervous system?
A research at Arlington       University, United states says that students with high performance and better memory are observed with their pupil dilated
https://www.uta.edu/news/news-releases/2024/04/22/eye-opener-pupils-enlarge-when-people-focus-on-tasks
Can we say that this all is occurring due to activation of sympathetic nervous system which releases  adrenaline and nor adrenaline from nerves
And according to this site:
"Sympathetic Nervous System - an overview | ScienceDirect Topics" https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/sympathetic-nervous-system
A complex mechanism is activated in brain which also includes amyglada (from limbic system) and it leads to storage of memories
I am just trying to decode it so that could be or not the mechanism?

I would say what is accurate in this context is that pupil dilation is being used as a marker of sympathetic activation. Here's a review article about autonomic control of the pupil:
McDougal, D. H., & Gamlin, P. D. (2015). Autonomic control of the eye. Comprehensive physiology, 5(1), 439.
The specific mechanism for the association with memory is not being tested in this study, it's only a correlative result.

“Can we say that this is occurring due to activation of sympathetic nervous system which releases adrenaline and noradrenaline from nerves?”
Of course not!
All one has is an external observation. One can formulate various hypotheses as to the mechanism responsible, but the essence of scientific logic is that the hypotheses need testing by experiments that address them directly.
